# select() Blocks in a While Loop when I press Enter Twice

Tags: c

So, I want this program to wait for 5 seconds for an input. If there is no input it returns. If there is input, it renews the timer and starts the count again.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
   fd_set rfds;
   struct timeval tv;
   int retval;
   char buf[1024];

   /* Watch stdin (fd 0) to see when it has input. */

   FD_ZERO(&rfds);
   FD_SET(0, &rfds);

   /* Wait up to five seconds. */


   do {
       tv.tv_sec = 5;
        tv.tv_usec = 0;
       printf("Please enter a number: \n");
        retval = select(1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
        /* Don't rely on the value of tv now! */

        if (retval == -1)
           perror("select()");
        else if (retval) {
           scanf("%[^\n]%*c", buf);
        }
        else
           printf("No data within five seconds.\n");
   } while (tv.tv_sec != 0 && tv.tv_usec != 0);

   exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

It works fine with regular input, but when I press enter twice, it goes into infinite loop. Why? What is happening?

Comment: `scanf("%[^\n]%*c", buf);` not allow newline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put `FD_SET(0, &rfds);` within the loop...
... if it select times out, the `rfds` structure will be reset
as if `FD_ZERO()` had been called....

Additionally, I might suggest you change the `scanf()` to a more simple `fgets()` if moving the `FD_SET()` doesn't totally solve your problem (in any event, `FD_SET` needs to be moved).